# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am working on a project to communicate between Arduino and Android via bluetooth module. But when I run it it crashes with illegal Argument exception. Here are the java codes and logcat error. Please help!

The Codes seem to be too long. But I hope only the bluetooth address part has the problem. Thank you.

**DeviceListActivity.java**

```
package com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate;

import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {
    // Debugging for LOGCAT
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
    private static final boolean D = true;


    // declare button for launching website and textview for connection status
    Button tlbutton;
    TextView textView1;

    // EXTRA string to send on to mainactivity
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    // Member fields
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.device_list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //***************
        checkBTState();

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connecting);
        textView1.setTextSize(40);
        textView1.setText(" ");

        // Initialize array adapter for paired devices
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

        // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
        ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Get a set of currently paired devices and append to 'pairedDevices'
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // Add previosuly paired devices to the array
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//make title viewable
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else {
            String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
        }
    }

    // Set up on-click listener for the list (nicked this - unsure)
    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

            textView1.setText("Connecting...");
            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Make an intent to start next activity while taking an extra which is the MAC address.
            Intent i = new Intent(DeviceListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    private void checkBTState() {
        // Check device has Bluetooth and that it is turned on
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // CHECK THIS OUT THAT IT WORKS!!!
        if (mBtAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (mBtAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
            } else {
                //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.util.UUID;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Handler;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnOn, btnOff;
    TextView txtArduino, txtString, txtStringLength, sensorView0, sensorView1, sensorView2, sensorView3;
    Handler bluetoothIn;

    final int handlerState = 0;                         //used to identify handler message
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    // SPP UUID service - this should work for most devices
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // String for MAC address
    private static String address;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Link the buttons and textViews to respective views
        btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
        btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff);
        txtString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtString);
        txtStringLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView1);
        sensorView0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView0);
        sensorView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView1);
        sensorView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView2);
        sensorView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView3);

        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                        //if message is what we want
                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                    recDataString.append(readMessage);                                    //keep appending to string until ~
                    int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                    // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
                        String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string
                        txtString.setText("Data Received = " + dataInPrint);
                        int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();                            //get length of data received
                        txtStringLength.setText("String Length = " + String.valueOf(dataLength));

                        if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')                                //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                        {
                            String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, 5);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                            String sensor1 = recDataString.substring(6, 10);            //same again...
                            String sensor2 = recDataString.substring(11, 15);
                            String sensor3 = recDataString.substring(16, 20);

                            sensorView0.setText(" Sensor 0 Voltage = " + sensor0 + "V");    //update the textviews with sensor values
                            sensorView1.setText(" Sensor 1 Voltage = " + sensor1 + "V");
                            sensorView2.setText(" Sensor 2 Voltage = " + sensor2 + "V");
                            sensorView3.setText(" Sensor 3 Voltage = " + sensor3 + "V");
                        }
                        recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data
                        // strIncom =" ";
                        dataInPrint = " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
        checkBTState();


        // Set up onClick listeners for buttons to send 1 or 0 to turn on/off LED
        btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("0");    // Send "0" via Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("1");    // Send "1" via Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
        //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Get MAC address from DeviceListActivity via intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //Get the MAC address from the DeviceListActivty via EXTRA
        address = intent.getStringExtra(com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate.DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        //create device and set the MAC address
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                //insert code to deal with this
            }
        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
        //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
        mConnectedThread.write("x");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            //Don't leave Bluetooth sockets open when leaving activity
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            //insert code to deal with this
        }
    }

    //Checks that the Android device Bluetooth is available and prompts to be turned on if off
    private void checkBTState() {

        if (btAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            } else {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    //create new class for connect thread
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        //creation of the connect thread
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                //Create I/O streams for connection
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }


        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //write method
        public void write(String input) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //if you cannot write, close the application
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat error:**

```
04-14 11:24:55.527 12525-12525/? V/ActivityThread: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{5155e9d token=android.os.BinderProxy@75b4f12 {com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate/com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate.MainActivity}} startsNotResumed=false
04-14 11:24:55.555 12525-12525/? V/ActivityThread: ActivityRecord{5155e9d token=android.os.BinderProxy@75b4f12 {com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate/com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate.MainActivity}}: app=android.app.Application@34458e0, appName=com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate, pkg=com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate, comp={com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate/com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate.MainActivity}, dir=/data/app/com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate-1/base.apk
04-14 11:24:55.557 12525-12525/? W/Typeface: getVibeFontPathWithCTS(): fontPath = /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
04-14 11:24:55.557 12525-12525/? W/Typeface: getVibeFontPathWithCTS(): fontName = 
04-14 11:24:55.557 12525-12525/? W/Typeface: getVibeFontPathWithCTS(): isForceToSystemDefault = false
04-14 11:24:55.557 12525-12525/? W/Typeface: VIBEUI_setThemeFont(): Is Not a file:/system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
04-14 11:24:55.571 12525-12525/? E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
04-14 11:24:55.572 12525-12525/? D/wangcy9: not using Theme.DeviceDefault / Theme.DeviceDefault.Light
04-14 11:24:55.593 12525-12533/? I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 4
04-14 11:24:55.594 12525-12525/? D/BluetoothAdapter: isEnabled
04-14 11:24:55.596 12525-12525/? V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{5155e9d token=android.os.BinderProxy@75b4f12 {com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate/com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate.MainActivity}}
04-14 11:24:55.606 12525-12525/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-14 11:24:55.607 12525-12525/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate, PID: 12525
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate/com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3333)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3364)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2671)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address
                                                       at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.<init>(BluetoothDevice.java:667)
                                                       at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BluetoothAdapter.java:631)
                                                       at com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:127)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6691)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3318)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3364) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2671) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
04-14 11:24:59.681 12525-12525/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12525 SIG: 9
```

Comment: This line causes the trouble   address = intent.getStringExtra(com.example.sparker.bluetoothintegrate.DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS); Whenever the intent extra's  doesn't have a value set for that it remain null and this is causing the crash can add a null check prior to do the bluetooth stuff

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can you please help a bit further with the proper code for this! This would be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

```
       //create device and set the MAC address
       BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

      try {
                if (BluetoothAdapter.checkBluetoothAddress(address)) {
                    //It is a valid MAC address.
                    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                    btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Invalid MAC: Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

By using above code, I tried to solve my problem, hope it will help you.

```
https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary
```

This library will helpful to you.